# Evaluating the line integral of $\sqrt{1 + 4x^2z^2}$ over the curve of intersection of $x^2 + z^2 = 1$ and $y = x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, curves, line-integrals

I am trying to evaluate the line integral of the function $f(x, y, z) = \sqrt{1 + 4x^2z^2}$ over the curve of intersection of $x^2 + z^2 = 1$ and $y = x^2$. Since at the curve $x^2 + z^2 = 1 \Longleftrightarrow y = 1 - z^2$, $f(x, y, z) = \sqrt{1 + 4yz^2} = \sqrt{1 + 4(1 - z^2)z^2} = \sqrt{1 + 4z^2 - 4z^4}$. Thus I figured that a parametrization of $z \in [-1 ,1], y = 1 - z^2$ is sufficient, but then as $r(z) = (z, 1 - z^2)$, $||r'(z)|| = \sqrt{1 + 4z^2}$ so that $f(r(z))||r'(z)|| = \sqrt{1 + 8z^2 + 12z^4 - 16z^6}$. Is this really the way of evaluating the line integral, or is there an easier way I haven't figured out?

Comment: Your calculation of $||r'(z)||$ is incorrect. Also note that with the parametrization you have used, you will have to use trigonometric substitution in the end to evaluate the integral. So parametrization used in the below answer is optimal here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrize the path $(x,y,z) = (\cos t, \cos^2 t, \sin t)$ and the integral is simply

$$\int_0^{2\pi} 1 + \sin^2 2t \:dt = 3\pi$$